# How to use variables as conditionals in steps of Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Azure Pipelines defines variables and conditions for the use in different pipeline tasks, steps and soon. When defining the following YAML pipeline, the step `ReleaseOnlyScript` should only be executed when the combined condition evaluated by the variable `isValidReleaseBuild` is `true`. In the Azure Pipeline DevOps Site, a variable `BuildType`is defined and set to `release`.

```
variables:
  - name: isValidReleaseBuild
    value: $[and(eq(variables['BuildType'], 'release'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/v'))]

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "BuildType: $(BuildType)"
      echo "SourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)"
      echo "ReleaseBuild: $(isValidReleaseBuild)"
    displayName: 'Buildinfo'
  - ${{ if eq(variables['isValidReleaseBuild'], true) }}:
    - script: |
        echo "YEAH its a Release!"
      displayName: 'ReleaseOnlyScript'
```

When running the pipeline, only the script `BuildInfo` is executed with the following output.

```
BuildType: release
SourceBranch: refs/tags/v1.0.0
ReleaseBuild: True
```

Why is the `ReleaseOnlyScript` not executed?

**Update:**
Thx to [Alex AIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60728480/13078117)'s answer, I modified the pipeline as follows and it works now as expected.

```
variables:
  - name: isValidReleaseBuild
    value: $[and(eq(variables['BuildType'], 'release'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/v'))]

jobs:
  - job: check_cicd
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo "BuildType: $(BuildType)"
          echo "SourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)"
          echo "ReleaseBuild: $(isValidReleaseBuild)"
          if [ "$(isValidReleaseBuild)" = "True" ]; then
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ValidBuild;isOutput=true]True"
          else
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ValidBuild;isOutput=true]False"
          fi
        name: buildinfo
  - job: release_cicd
    dependsOn: check_cicd
    condition: eq(dependencies.check_cicd.outputs['buildinfo.ValidBuild'], 'True')
    steps:
      - template: build-release.yml
```

Comment: In my case, I needed to skip some steps depending on the output variable of a previous step within a job and I was able to do
`condition: eq(variables['<step_name>.<variable_name>'], 'True')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

You have to use `condition` within your step, not an expression at the beginning.

```
parameters:
  doThing: false

steps:
- script: echo I did a thing
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.doThing }}', true))
```

Comment: Thx, the condition did the trick. In my case, I added a separate job checking the validity of the pipeline configuration and output to a variable with ```task.setvariable```. The dependent job then uses that variable in its condition. Works.

Comment: Note: The syntax `eq('${{ parameters.doThing }}', true)` works **only in templates** and not in the _azure-pipelines.yml_. If you want to check a condition against a variable in _azure-pipelines.yml_ this syntax is needed: `eq(variables['doThing'], true)`.

Comment: Is there any documentation that clearly explains when you use the various syntax for comparison: `eq('parameters.doThing', true)` vs `eq('${{parameters.doThing}}', true)` vs `eq(parameters['doThing'], true)` ?