# Conditional template is not executed when condition is met in Yml file (Azure Pipelines)

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I've this yml template

```
parameters:

# List of sub jobs
- name: subJobs
  type: object
  default:
    buildId: ''
    useHttps: ''

jobs:
- job: ComplexJobs
  strategy:
    matrix:
      ${{ each subJob in parameters.subJobs }}:
        ${{ subJob.name }}:
          buildId: ${{ subJob.buildId }}
          useHttps: ${{ subJob.useHttps }}

pool:
  name: myPool

steps:

- ${{ if ne(variables['buildId'], '') }}:
  - template: execute-custom-template.yml
```

It recevies an array of elements as input parameter and create sub jobs from that. My issue is the first step: even if the `buildId` parameter is provided, the step is not executed.
I think I'm evaluating that condition in a wrong way. Could someone please give me some tips/suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It won't work because the expression is evaluated at compile time, but the variable does not yet exist at this time. Does this answer your question? [How to use variables as conditionals in steps of Azure Pipelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728394/how-to-use-variables-as-conditionals-in-steps-of-azure-pipelines)